# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() errordasd

Tags: php

I have this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\AppServ\www\admin paneli\yenikayit.php on line 131

Here is my code

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_FILES["resim"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    //$error 0 ise hata yoktur, yüklemeye başlayalım.
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $dosya_ad = $_FILES["resim"]["name"][$key];
        $dosya    = $_FILES["resim"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $i        = 1;
        $ad       = "app_images/". $dosya_ad;
        //uye adlı klasöre(dizine) yükleyelim
        move_uploaded_file($dosya, "./app_images/" . $dosya_ad);



//Durumu bildirelim
echo $i ? "Yüklendi" : "Hata oldu";

if ($_POST["ekle"]){
$sonuc=$db->query("INSERT INTO uygulama(no,baslik,aciklama,resimler,resim,tur,yapimci,boyut,indirmelinki,APK,tarih) VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, '$ad', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"); 
if ($sonuc === false) die ("sorgu hatası".$db->error);
      if (!$sonuc) {
        die('Kayıt eklenmedi');
    }
    else{
        echo "Başarıyla Kaydedildi";
    }
}
}
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_FILES["resim"]["error"])` show?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check to exists variable before foreach:

```
$i = 0;
if(!empty($_FILES["resim"]["error"])) {
    foreach ($_FILES["resim"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        //$error 0 ise hata yoktur, yüklemeye başlayalım.
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { ...
```